# PHP class_alias returns error

Tags: php, class, oop, alias

I just wanted to create an alias for my database class using the following code:

```
 <?php
class MySqlDatabase extends engine{
class_alias ('MySqlDatabase','Db');

public static $connection;
// etc.
}
?>
```

When I run the code in PHP 5.6.19 I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class_alias' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /(somedir)/dbconnect.php on line 18

Am I doing something wrong here?
According the the PHP manual the function is available on PHP 5 >= 5.3.0 - PHP 7

Comment: you are creating class alias in the class. put class_alias ('MySqlDatabase','Db');
 outside of class

Comment: Inside a class definition, you can have either constant, property or method definitions, you can't arbitrarily have calls to PHP functions

Comment: @Robin please mark my answer as correct so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define alias like this

```
<?php
class MySqlDatabase extends engine{


public static $connection;
// etc.
}
 class_alias ('MySqlDatabase','Db');

?>
```

[check the link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php)

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

I looked over the fact that I have to define the alias outside the class.